# Specifying lower priority backup IP for a nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone

Let's assume that I use EasyDNS as a DNS service provider.

There I have an `A`-record entry for `ns-at-premises.example.com` pointing to the IP address `192.0.2.123`, where a DNS server is located, at my premises, listening on port 53.

There's also a `CNAME`-record entry for `ns.example.com` with the value of `ns-at-premises.example.com` (I read somewhere that `NS`-Records should get `CNAMEd`).

`example.com` has an `A`-record of `192.0.2.234`, a VPS hosted on AWS and `www.example.com` has a `CNAME` of `example.com`, but that is irrelevant.

There is a subdomain `dynamic.example.com` which has a `NS`-Record of `ns.example.com`, which will send any request for `*.dynamic.example.com` or `dynamic.example.com` to be resolved at `192.0.2.123`, where `*` can be anyting.

--

What I now want to do is add a backup nameserver in case `192.0.2.123` goes down. This means that a port-53 server at `192.0.2.124` should get queried in case `192.0.2.123` is not reachable.

I would add an `A`-Record for `ns-backup.example.com` pointing to `192.0.2.124`, and a `CNAME` for `ns2.example.com` with the value of `ns-backup.example.com`

--

The question is, how can I now tell EasyDNS that `dynamic.example.com` should query or redirect to `ns2.example.com` when `ns.example.com` is not reachable?

I read that just adding a second `NS`-Record with the value of `ns2.example.com` to `dynamic.example.com` would result in clients using `ns.example.com` and `ns2.example.com` for lookups in a Round-Robin fashion, but what I actually want is that `ns2.example.com` only gets queried if `ns.example.com` is down.

So I am actually looking for a way to add weights to the nameservers, like `MX`-Records are able to provide.

Is this possible? Or must I settle with the idea that none of those two nameservers will be a primary and deal with them as loadbalanced non-prioritized servers?

Comment: There's no such thing. It's only round robin.

Comment: This problem is not solvable in DNS. You could use a loadbalancer to have one of the nodes be a standby DNS server and the other handle all traffic; as soon as ns1 would fail the loadbalancer would route all traffic to ns2. In this case both DNS servers would be reachable under the ip address of the loadbalancer (or a dedicated service ip for the DNS service) though.

Comment: "I read somewhere that NS-Records should get CNAMEd)."  I do not know where you read that but it is in fact almost the contrary: it is not recommended to have `NS` records pointing at `CNAME` for the extra performance hit and risk of broken link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to be fixed with **ns1.example.com** and **ns2.example.com**. You just need to have valid record for NS so even directly **ns-at-premises.example.com** can be set up as name server and no **ns1.example.com** cname is needed to be set up.

As has been already mentioned here there is not available use case you are asking about... What you can do is set up master on **ns1** which would notify the changes to **ns2** which would pull the changes to local cache so "standard" master/slave configuration.

At that moment you can have both DNS resolving the same response so at the end you don't need to care which DNS server has provide the answer. Even **ns1** would be temporarily unavailable the **ns2** would have still valid cached information for the time of **ns1**'s outage.

What may be also the case is to have "hidden" nameserver at premisses which would not be even propagated to the DNS. There could be just handled the changes and act as master. Other DNS server which would be located in DC (for example) can be announced in DNS as NS for the domain. Any changes done during **at-premises** online status could be directly propagated to (pulled into) publicly known NS server. In case of outage the changes will be propagated with next successful check once **ns1** is up.

There is nowhere required that "real master" where the zone records are handled have to be all the time publicly available. It has to be available enough to not expire the zones cached on the slaves. For DNS functionality all NS listed in the domain definition (mainly upper NS - for example.com it is NS for .com) can be even all slaves as for resolving purpose there is no difference. The role of master/slave is just for zone maintenance purpose (where it is handled).

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up regarding the CNAME indirection.

Answer (score 2):

The DNS protocol does not provide a mechanism to designate primary and backup name servers.

You can set up multiple name servers that are authoritative but each of them is expected to respond (and usually to return identical responses to identical queries)  and all of them will be queried.